# Swift & iOS8 : SKLabelNode not showing up

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8

So I'm trying to learn Swift and Sprite kit and I started following this Apple tutorial (you might need to login to Apple Developer):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW1

I translated the code given from Obj-C to Swift and it works quite well BUT my SKLabelNode named helloNode is not showing up despite the fact that Sprite kit is telling me that there is indeed 1 node on scene.

Here's the code:

```
class HelloScene: SKScene {
var contentCreated = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    if(!self.contentCreated) {
        createSceneContents()
        contentCreated = true
    }
}

func createSceneContents() {
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit
    self.addChild(newHelloNode())
}

func newHelloNode() -> SKLabelNode {
    let helloNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    helloNode.text = "Hello, World!"
    helloNode.fontSize = 42
    helloNode.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    helloNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    return helloNode
}
```

}

HelloScene is instantiated and successfully added to the main View Controller.

Thanks!

Comment: `helloNode is not showing up`  What do you mean `not showing up`?  Not showing up where?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The label node appears in the scene when I run it.

Comment: I mean it's not displayed, I just have a blue background and nothing else, no text.

Comment: @0x141E What version of XCode do you use? Which Simulator ? Thanks!

Comment: Xcode 6 beta 4. iPad 2.

Comment: Hiya, did you find anything on this, I am also having problems getting a SKLabel to show on Xcode Version 6.2 (6C107a) iPad2 Simulator. I am adding it programatically, it shows on iPad Air/Retina and it shows if I add it directly to the scene.sks?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The issue is with auto layout in xcode 6. The scene is being loaded before the auto layout settings are set. In the ViewController place the initialization of the scene and presentScene in viewDidLayoutSubviews like so:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();

    let hello = HelloScene.new();
    hello.size = skView.bounds.size;
    hello.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill;

    skView.presentScene(hello);
}
```